# Prevent content from shifting horizontally on scrollbar show/hide

Tags: jquery, css

How to fix page on center (Example: vk.com).
On this site, if show/hide scrollbar - containers position not shift left/right.

I have two containers:

```
<header class="topPage" style="width:100%;height:50px;position:fixed;top:0;left:0;">
    <div class="wrap" style="margin:0 auto;width:860px;">
    </div>
</header>
```

and

```
<section class="centerPage" style="width:100%;position:relative;padding-top:50px; display:inline-block">
    <div class="wrap" style="margin:0 auto;width:860px;">
    </div>
</section>
```

Me need make fix ALL containers if scrollbar show/hide. Thanks.

Comment: I can see vk.com, can you put a screenshot?

Comment: There's some javascript running on resize event that is fixing the width of the parent element on the page, so even if the scrollbar disappears this is not changing the position of the inner element

Comment: One simple method is to use `html { overflow-y: scroll; }` to always show a scroll bar. The bar is always there so it will not cause page jumps.

Answer (score 0):

First, Give `width` for Container Div.

Second, give `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;position:fixed;` for Container div.

That will work.

Answer (score -1):

Just put `margin: 0 auto;` on your container element.

It means margin top and bottom are set to 0 and left and right are set to auto, which will center your container.

**EDIT**

If you inspect the container element of the website you linked, you will see that they do exactly the same thing.

**EDIT 2**

The site will set the width of a container around the content, we'll name this `scrollFix`, minus the width of the scrollbar on document ready with javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var documentWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
    $('.scrollFix').width(documentWidth - 16); // 16px for scrollbar width
    $('.container').width(documentWidth * 0.8); // 0.8 for 80% of the page
});
```

The jsFiddle for the example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/fT3Rm/1/

**EDIT NUMERO 3**

So with an HTML structure as following:

```
<header id="header">
    <div class="wrap"></div>
</header> Second - 
<section id="section-1">
    <div class="wrap"></div>
</section>
```

You can use this jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var documentWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
    $('#header, #section-1').width(documentWidth - 16); // 16px for scrollbar width
    $('.wrap').width(documentWidth * 0.8); // 0.8 for 80% of the page
});
```

This way, the header and section element have a 100% width minus the scrollbar width. The wrap divs should be `margin: 0 auto;` and in the function you can change the 0.8 to any percentage you want, 0.7 for 70%, 0.6 for 60%, etc..

You should also set the header and the section to `position: relative;` so it won't move.
So in your CSS:

```
#header, #section-1 {
    position: relative;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fT3Rm/3/

Comment: as for the other answer: margin 0 auto alone will not avoid a page shift when the scrollbar disappears. He is asking why the page is still centered when the scrollbar is either visible or not

Comment: i have two containers, first - <header><div class="wrap"></div></header>

Second - <section><div class="wrap"></div></section>

header and section have width 100%, wrap - margin:0 auto

Your method doesn't work .. please, give such more versions ..

Comment: $('.wrap').width(documentWidth * 0.8); 

me need only 860px width, can i have this ?

Comment: Yes you can also just remove
 this whole line and keep the 860px in your CSS.

Comment: I've edited my answer, try adding the `position: relative;` in your CSS.